# Casting Strint to integer in liferay dynamic query

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I have been using dynamic query for a project.

Here is an scenario for which I am facing problem.

For a table xyz the column `version` is stored as `varchar` (I know it's a poor design, but it's too late to change now) and has values as `9,12`.

For the query :

```
select max(version) 
from xyz 
where something = 'abc';
```

I am getting the output as 9 instead of 12.

The dynamic query for the same is:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = PortletBeanLocatorUtil.getBeanLocator(ClpSerializer.getServletContextName()).getClassLoader();

DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(xyz.class, classLoader);
                    dynamicQuery.setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.max("version"));
                    dynamicQuery.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("something").eq("abc"));

List<Object> list = xyzLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
```

The query which is giving the correct value is :

```
select max(cast(version as signed)) 
from xyz 
where something = 'abc';
```

Now, I want it to be in the dynamic query, how can I do that?

I am using liferay-6.2-ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **ProjectionFactoryUtil.sqlProjection** method.
That method allows using functions that are executed by SQL engine.

For example, I am using following code in order to get the max length of a string column called 'content':

```
Projection maxSizeProjection = ProjectionFactoryUtil.sqlProjection(
        "max(length(content)) as maxSize", new String[] {"maxSize"},
        new Type[] {Type.BIG_DECIMAL});
```

The same thing can be done with dynamic query criterions using **RestrictionsFactoryUtil.sqlRestriction** in case you want to use a SQL function in a condition.

In your case try following code:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ProjectionFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.Type;

...

Projection maxSizeProjection = ProjectionFactoryUtil.sqlProjection(
        "max(cast(version as signed)) as maxVersion",
        new String[] {"maxVersion"}, new Type[] {Type.BIG_DECIMAL});

dynamicQuery.setProjection(maxSizeProjection);
```

Comment: This worked absolutely fine for me :) Thanks alot :)